# Rotate header and page number on a horizontal A3 page within an A4 document

Tags: koma-script, rotating

Good morning, I am writing my thesis and should insert an A3 page in the A4 document to be folded once printed in order to insert a very large diagram. I need to keep the layout of the A4 page and then write on the left of the A3 page horizontally, with only the image exceeding the A4 size expanding to the right.
I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[%
    corpo=11pt,
    twoside,
    stile=classica,
    oldstyle,
    tipotesi=custom,
    greek,
    evenboxes,
]{toptesi}
\usepackage[paper=A4,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
    bookmarksopen,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue},
    citecolor={blue},
    urlcolor={blue}
  }
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\newcommand\fillin[1][4cm]{\makebox[#1]{\dotfill}} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{-1} } 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{osservazione}{Osservazione}
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style= numeric,
    sorting=none,
    defernumbers=true
  ]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{references.bib} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}\errorcontextlines=9
\figurespagetrue
\indici
\mainmatter
\chapter{AAA}
\section{BBB}
\lipsum[150]

\afterpage{% Insert after the current page
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{sideways}
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,pagesize} 
\recalctypearea
\section{lalala}
\lipsum[100] \newline
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Picture}
        \caption{caption}\label{caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{sideways}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}

\newpage
\section{CCC}

\end{document}
```

What I get is text printed on the left side of the page and not on the right, and header and page number printed rotated by 90°.

Comment: You've not shown a minimal working example. So I can only suggest to use the solution from the KOMA-Script manual section 20.2.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem and how you have tried to correct it.. As it is you leave us to guess what you might or might not have done.

Comment: @PeterWilson thank you for the answer, I've just edited the post

Comment: @elia Your example is still neither minimal, e.g., loading packages more than once and loading not used packages, nor working, because it results in errors. → https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: If you edit your question please show the edits otherwise how do you expect anyone to be able to understand what is going on? Do you know what is going on? --- GOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your example was neither working (there are several error messages) nor minimal (there are several unused and even multiply loaded packages). So I have had to make my own example:

```
\documentclass[%
    corpo=11pt,% unknown option
    twoside,
    stile=classica,% unknown option
    oldstyle,
    tipotesi=custom,% unknown option
    greek,
    evenboxes,
]{toptesi}
\usepackage[paper=A4,usegeometry]{typearea}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\errorcontextlines=\maxdimen
\chapter{AAA}
\section{BBB}
\lipsum[150]

\clearpage
\storeareas\Aivarea% see KOMA-Script manual section 20.2
\KOMAoption{paper}{a3,landscape}% -"-
\areaset[current]{\dimexpr\textwidth+.5\paperwidth\relax}{\textheight}% -"-
\restoregeometry% But dont use, the enlarged area, use the area of geometry
\section{lalala}
\lipsum[100]

\begin{figure}
  \makebox[\textwidth][l]{% avoid overfull \hbox
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+.5\paperwidth\relax}% extend the width
                                % for the image and caption
      \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\textwidth,height=.7\textheight]{example-image}% Just an example image
      \caption{Example image}\label{fig:example}
    \end{minipage}%
  }
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\Aivarea

\section{CCC}

\end{document}
```

[image: three pages: first a4 portrait, second a3 landscape, third a4 portrait]

See section 20.2 of the KOMA-Script manuals for more information about inserting an A3-landscape-page into a A4-document.